# MSAL.js Twitter popup not redirecting after incorrect login attempt

Tags: javascript, azure-ad-b2c, msal.js, twitter-login

I am using Azure MSAL library in a vanilla js application running in localhost and I step up with a problem in the login flow with Twitter.

I am using the `loginPopup()` approach and it seems to work fine. When I choose to sign in with Twitter it asks for my credentials and if I enter them right, the popup closes and the login works.

The problem is when I type the wrong credentials

[image: First login redirection to Twitter]

It redirects me (inside the popup) to another Twitter page

[image: Second redirection inside the popup window]

Then if I enter the right credentials I get redirected to my page inside the popup window and it does not close itself. And on the original page, I am not logged in.

This the URL generated after the wrong redirect that stays in the popup and does not close itself.

`https://localhost:3001/#state=asdasdasd...&client_info=asdasdasd....&code=asdasdasd...`

This is my msalConfig:

```
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: process.env.B2C_CLIENTID,
        authority: process.env.B2C_AUTHORITY,
        knownAuthorities: [process.env.B2C_KNOWN_AUTHORITIES],
        redirectUri: process.env.B2C_REDIRECT_URL
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false
    }
};
```

And my login method:

```
constructor() {
        this.account = null;
        this.myMSALObj = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
        this.myMSALObj.handleRedirectPromise()
            .then((resp) => { this.handleResponse(resp); })
            .catch(console.error);
    }
    loginWithTwitter() {
        this.myMSALObj.loginPopup()
            .then(response => {
                utils.setSocialId(response.uniqueId);
                utils.setSocialApplication(Constants.SOCIAL_APPLICATION.TWITTER);
                const socialIdentity = {
                    email: response.idTokenClaims.emails[0],
                    name: response.idTokenClaims.name,
                    socialApplication: Constants.SOCIAL_APPLICATION.TWITTER,
                    userId: response.uniqueId
                };
                login.loginPlayerWithSocialIdentity(socialIdentity);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(`Error signing in with Twitter: ${error}`);
            });
    }
```

Comment: For this scenario, how about using `myMSALObj.loginRedirect()` instead of `myMSALObj.loginPopup()`?

Comment: The web application is supposed to run inside an iframe in some scenarios, where a redirect is not an option for security reasons